# Video Playback on Win7/Vista [dshow, dmo]

Tags: directshow, dmo

I have a video clip that has some issues on default install of Win7: video plays without sound. The video clip comes from a mobile phone, it's a 3gp (mp4) file format with H264 video and AMR audio.
I wanted to find out what I can do to add playback support for AMR audio on that machine. VLC or klite/ffdshow codec packs are out of the question here. I tried to use AMR dshow decoder from MonoGram but it doesn't solve the problem. When I tried to see the graph in MonoGram graph studio it doesn't show me the graph how win7 at all is able to play the video. Seems like it doesn't use dshow filters/decoders in case of this video clip.
So the questions is: how does it play the clip and how can I extend default os functionality to make my clip playable.

Comment: There is no AMR decoder in clean Windows install, so you need a third party decoder (ACM codec, DirectShow filter, DMO, MFT) to enable decoding and playback.

Comment: The thing is that I wrote my own amr dshow decoder, it works if I have ffdshow installed (I know ffdshow also has it, but graph studio shows my decoder and it plays well), otherwise windows media player doesn't use it. GraphStudio also doesn't create playback graph for that video if there is no ffdshow. Basically, there is something else is missing, and media player plays it without sound.

Comment: Note that WMP attempts to not use DirectShow in first place. There might be something wrong with your decoder, in terms that it does not behave itself correctly to be a part of [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).